# Can fitness functions be of the type "minimum-value as best-value" in GA?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have implemented a genetic algorithm, in which the fitness function considers the coefficient of variation of the data as the fitness value, and so the closer the COV is to zero, the better. Will it still be called the fitness function? Usually the fitness value is defined such that the **greater** the value, the better.

Comment: Just make sure you are sorting your genomes right. In your setup, after each generation, I think you want to sort the genomes so that the one who has the least fitness is the best. Maybe, it is worth considering to multiply the fitness with (-1) to not change the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract & direct answer would be fitness function is a measure for your solutions and it should be well defined to drive the search space to a near-optimal solution you want to achieve for your problem instance. You can find more for designing fitness function here: [A guide for fitness function design](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2001858.2001929)

You can definitely have an EA for the maximization or minimization problem. A general evolutionary cycle is shown in the image below (from one of the text book-Introduction to Evolutionary Computing). As per the EA cycle, you need to evaluate your solutions after the population is created, and after offsprings are created. Basically, survivor selection is the process where you would like to focus on maximization or minimization, and your problem is minimization. For your problem, you might want to adopt one of the following approaches:

1. When you create your fitness function, you can negate the fitness. And make sure in this approach you have to choose the highest fitness individuals for next-generation (aka in survivor selection).
2. Let your fitness function be positive. But as you want to approach as a minimization problem, you have to choose the lowest fitness individuals for next-generation (aka in survivor selection).

[image: Evolutionary Cycle]